# Print previous 4th line using awk or sed?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

I want to print the previous 4th line(Calling_party_IP) and 2nd line (Called number), as every time there is an INVITE message (CSeq:1 INVIte) appears inline

sample input:

```
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
        Via: SIP/2.0/UDP calling_party_IP:58929;branch=z9hG4bK93464974;received=calling_party_IP;rport=34653
        From: <sip:98745@ip>;tag=123456
        To: <sip:called number@ip>;tag=as4463463edc
        Call-ID: some string
        CSeq: 1 INVITE
        Server:
        Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, PRACK, MESSAGE
        Supported: replaces, timer
        Content-Length: 0000
```

sample Output:

```
calling_party_IP
called number
```

Comment: I suggest to show a larger part of the input file and the output you want to get. If there are other lines before and after the interesting part, show these as well, it might be cleare if the example input contains at least two matching groups of lines.

Comment: Can the group of 5 lines (from 4 lines before the match to the match) overlap another group of 5 lines?

Comment: I just made a clear view, as you asked.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my guess what the question means, I have this.
(Edit: The question has been improved, and my guess appears to have been correct.)

Basic idea is to store each line into a 4 long array, and when things match print out the 2nd and 4th lines before. So an input of

```
ant
bee
cat
dog
eel
fun
```

looking for `fun` will print out `bee` and `dog`.

```
awk '/fun/{ print saved[(NR-4)%4],saved[(NR-2)%4]} {saved[NR%4]=$0}' file
```

This allows for overlapping blocks of 5 lines ending in the pattern.

Comment: Although it worked but, For the particular case, it is displaying 3 lines, instead of 2

Comment: I can't reproduce the "displaying 3 lines , instead of 2". At the moment it displays 1 line. Replacing the print statement with `print saved[(NR-4)%4]; print saved[(NR-2)%4]` will make it print 2 lines.